# how do i create recursively nested zip files

Tags: linux, bash, zip

Opposite version of this question: [How do I recusively unzip nested ZIP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208857/how-do-i-recusively-unzip-nested-zip-files)

let's say I have a file. I want to zip it to 1.zip, than zip 1.zip to 2.zip etc. I want to specify the number. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't compress a compressed file for any gains-- what are you actually asking?

Comment: A compressed file always contains a small amount of additional data to enable decompression, in addition to the compressed data itself. If compressing a compressed file only saves 50 bytes, but you need 100 bytes of additional data, you wind up with a *larger* file.

Comment: Since `zip` is a container format, and not just a compression scheme, it would make sense if you want to combine two or more `zip` files into one, but repeated the same single file doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple loop to do this, although there's no good reason to do so.

```
zip_count=5
i=1
fname=data.txt
while [ "$i" -lt "$zip_count" ]; do
    zip "$i" "$fname"
    fname="$i.zip"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```