# Extract a CSV inside a zip file inside another zip online in R?

Tags: r, download, unzip

I am attempting to extract a CSV that is inside of a zip file nested in another zip file posted online.

The analysis I am doing draws on files that usually have the same name but are updated regularly. Every so often they update format. This time they decided to put multiple versions of the data embedded in zip files inside of a larger zip file.

What have I done and tried?

I know have a list of many other file that I have downloaded and then loaded into objects. In all the cases the code block looks similar to this:

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://fakeurl.com/data/filename.zip",temp, mode="wb")
unzip(temp, "data.csv")
db <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T)
```

I cannot wrap my head around taking it to the next level. Because I am not downloading it 'directly' I do not know how to manipulate it.

Ideally, I want to unzip one file into a temp file, then unzipping the next file, then reading in the csv into a data frame.

I thank you all for your help and will answer any questions you might have to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the downloaded file into the current directory and then iterate through the generated files unzipping any that itself is a zip file.

```
Files <- unzip(temp)
for(File in Files) if (grepl("\\.zip$", File)) unzip(File)
```

There also various approaches listed here:

[How do I recursively unzip nested ZIP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208857/how-do-i-recursively-unzip-nested-zip-files)

[Creating zip file from folders in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668395/creating-zip-file-from-folders-in-r)

https://superuser.com/questions/1287028/how-to-explore-nested-zip-without-extract

https://github.com/ankitkaushal/nzip